# Closure in $H^1((0,L)\times\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega=(0,L)\times\mathbb{R}$ and consider the space 
$$V:=\{f\in H^2(\Omega) \ \vert \ f'(0,y)=f'(L,y)=0 \ \forall \ y\in\mathbb{R}\}.$$

I would like to show that the closure of $V$ with respect to $H^1(\Omega)$-norm is equal to $H^1(\Omega)$.

Can one maybe argue that $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ is contained in $V$ and since it is dense in $H^1(\Omega)$, then $\overline{V}=H^1(\Omega)$?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: $V$ is not well defined. The derivatives in the definition of $V$ donn't make sense for functions $f \in H^{2}(\Omega )$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy If $\Omega=(0,L)$, then $V$ would be the domain of the Neumann Laplacian, which is $\{ f\in H^2((0,L)) \ \vert \ f'(0)=f'(L)=0\}$. Here I am looking with something analogous but on the product space $(0,L)\times\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Be careful as $\overline{C_c^\infty(\Omega)}=H^1_0(\Omega) \neq H^1(\Omega)$.

But with $W=\left\{ f \in C_c^\infty(\overline{\Omega}) | \partial_x f(0,y)=\partial_x f(L,y)=0 \forall y \in \mathbb R  \right\}$ you can show that $W \subset V$ and $\overline{W}=H^1(\Omega)$.